# How to start an xterm from Nautilus, running in the folder I'm viewing?

Tags: linux, gnome, nautilus, xterm

This was easy in Thunar, but now I'm on a machine where I'm trying to do everything in the Gnome desktop world.

In Nautilus, I'm in some deep-down folder.   How do I open an xterm (rxvt, aterm, gnome's terminal app, whichever) with its working directory already set to the location Nautilus is showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very useful Nautilus extension called `nautilus-open-terminal` that does just what you asked. You should find it in the standard repositories.

Once installed you should have a "Open in terminal" entry in the File menu.

Comment: Added it using Synaptic. Still don't see any "open terminal here" or similar command.

Comment: @DarenW: sorry, I forgot to specify, it adds an entry in the File menu.

Comment: You will also need to restart nautilus.

Comment: @Kim: ah, now it works!  It took me a long time to realize that the whole desktop is really a view in Nautilus, so I had log out and back in.   I see what I want in File and also the right-click menu.  :)

Comment: @DarenW: another way to do it, without restarting would have been `killall nautilus`. This would have killed all the instances of nautilus, which then should have restarted automagically ;)

Answer (score 1):

A more general feature that works with both Dolphin/Nautilus and some Terminals like Gnome Terminal or Konsole is to just drag a folder over the terminal.  This will give you a quoted path to the folder.  You can use this after a cd command or other commands like cp, mv, ln, or whatever you might want.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method is to use Nautilus' built in script support. This gives the chance to execute scripts (which as variables get the file/folder path) you actuvated it on, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332213/bash-script-to-start-tmux-and-issue-commands).